# AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.postgres.fields' has no attribute 'JSONField'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Installing project from GitHub repo and receive following error after all

```
 File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/blog/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rest_framework import serializers
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1534, in <module>
    ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[postgres_fields.JSONField] = JSONField
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.postgres.fields' has no attribute 'JSONField'
```

Have no idea, what it's related to. Please help..

The whole traceback:

```
    File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/blog/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rest_framework import serializers
  File "/Users/TheKotik/closer/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1534, in <module>
    ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[postgres_fields.JSONField] = JSONField
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.postgres.fields' has no attribute 'JSONField'
```

Comment: compare the version you are using to the github one and tell me

Comment: ^^ JSONField was introduced in Django 1.9, if you're on something less than that, you won't have it.

Comment: @wpercy django version is 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Django version is too low. `JSONField` was added in Django 1.9 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#django-contrib-postgres)), so you'll need to upgrade in order to use `JSONField`

Comment: I needed to update project in production, so I'll have to update django version there as well? There is no way to stay on 1.8?

Comment: Not if you want to use `JSONField`. It literally didn't exist before 1.9. If your project has a requirements.txt file that it builds from, you should be able to just update the version number in there.